# Python memory error with f.read

Tags: python, bson, memory-consumption

I have problem with  memory in python "Python memory error". In fact , I try to recover  data from a big `.bson` file using this script:

```
with open('xxxx.bson','rb') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

error message :

```
data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
MemoryError
```

thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: How large is the file? I'm guessing it's a large file (larger than your system's available memory)? Right now you're reading *all* of the file in memory *twice* (once for the raw data, and once for the decoded data).

Comment: You can scan line after line if the file is too big: 'for line in f'

Comment: Thank you very much it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce memory consumption by switching to [`decode_file_iter`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/#bson.decode_file_iter), which 1) requires a file (not its contents) as input, and 2) returns a generator.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library:  https://github.com/bauman/python-bson-streaming

```
from bsonstream import KeyValueBSONInput
f = open("xxxx.bson", 'rb')
stream = KeyValueBSONInput(fh=f)
for dict_data in stream:
    print dict_data
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is OK.